# How to draw border arround arrow?

Tags: html, css

I want to draw border around entire arrow and the problem is on the right side cause it draws around square.

The reason is the right triangle is transparent and it sees it like that. Without that arrows won't be seen if they are colored the same.

Any ideas how to do that?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a0cj567/)

**HTML**

```css
.firstArrow {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 330px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 3;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.firstArrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top,red 50%,transparent 50%);
}

.firstArrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom,red 50%,transparent 50%);
}

.secondArrow {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  left: -20px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 50px;
  width: 330px;

}
.secondArrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;   
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top,blue 50%,transparent 50%);
}

.secondArrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom,blue 50%,transparent 50%);
}
.thirdArrow {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 330px;
  left: -40px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
}

.thirdArrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( to right bottom, green 50%,transparent 50%);
}
.thirdArrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( to right top, green 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="firstArrow"> 1 </div>
<div class="secondArrow"> 2 </div>
<div class="thirdArrow"> 3 </div>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4ZeCz/4133/

Comment: Seen it but didn't help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the shape differently using skew transformation:

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
}

.arrow:before,
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  left: -3px;
  right: 0;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background: var(--c, red);
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.arrow:after {
  transform: scaleY(-1) skewX(45deg);
}

.arrow:first-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"> 1 </div>
<div class="arrow" style="--c:blue;"> 2 </div>
<div class="arrow" style="--c:green;"> 3 </div>
```

Comment: offtopic question; what is up with '--c:blue;'? I don't understand this CSS markup

Comment: @Rumplin it's a CSS variable that allow to easily change the color without the need of defining a new class. The background is set with that variable `background: var(--c, red);` and I simply need to change `--c` to have a new color (red is the default one) .. read this if you want more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.firstArrow {
  background: red;
}

.secondArrow {
  background: blue;
}

.thirdArrow {
  background: green;
}

.firstArrow, .secondArrow, .thirdArrow {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.firstArrow::before, .secondArrow::before, .thirdArrow::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 41px;
    height: 41px;
    background: red;
    right: -21px;
    top: 9px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.secondArrow::before {
  background: blue;
}

.thirdArrow::before {
  background: green;
}

.firstArrow::after, .secondArrow::after, .thirdArrow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 49px;
  height: 49px;
  right: -26px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 5px;
}

.firstArrow::after {
  border-color: red;
}

.secondArrow::after {
  border-color: blue;
}

.thirdArrow::after {
  border-color: green;
}

.blue-border::before, .red-border::before, .green-border::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    transform: rotate(0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
    left: 0;
    top: -5px;
    background: transparent;
}

.blue-border::before {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.green-border::before {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="firstArrow red-border"> 1 </div>
   </div>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="secondArrow blue-border"> 2 </div>
   </div>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="thirdArrow green-border"> 3 </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check if you wanted something like this!

Comment: Well not quite what I had in mind. Just a line around entire arrow.

Comment: entire arrow! ok let me check that as well

Comment: for this you need to use two colors, one for border and other for the bg. else it won't show unless you give some space. try using two colors

Comment: Problem is that border for arrow:after and arrow:before is square not a triangle. Reason is cause one triangle is transparent but non the less still there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below sample. Hope it will meet your requirements.The right side arrow head and its border are created using pseudo elements `::before` and `::after`

```css
.firstArrow {
    position: relative;
    background: #eee;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: solid 3px #999;
}
.firstArrow:after,
.firstArrow:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

}
.firstArrow:before {
    top: 0;
    right: -50px;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 25px solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #eee;
}
.firstArrow:after{
    top: -3px;
    right: -58px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 28px solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstArrow">shape 1</div><div class="firstArrow">shape 2</div><div class="firstArrow">shape 3</div>
```